# Is this a genuine UFO sighting in London or a hoax?

Tags: ufo

Here's the link that was shared with me on Twitter: [UFOs seen in sky over London](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209104110/http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/3660007/UFOs-seen-in-day-over-London.html)

Something about it strikes me as fake but I'll let the experts judge.
Can anyone tell me how can this happen if it's not a genuine UFO sighting?

Comment: You're going to get complaints from the pedants, which includes me: UFO=Unidentified Flying Object. This is definitely a UFO. The real question is whether it is an alien spacecraft. Please edit.

Comment: interesting; there are two more videos ( [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQmut0XtD3s), [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiylJCma9c) ) supposedly of the same UFOs. However, considering we're talking about London, a city with a population of almost 8m, there should have been thousands of uploaded videos, not just three. Also, in the end the man filming seems so say "let's go; we've got fu**ing members of the", and it is assumed "public" followed. My guess is that this is a hoax, and all the filming people were a part of it.

Comment: @Oddthinking: The question is if it's a UFO or even that is a fake. Who said it's flying? It could be computer generated.

Comment: If the question is "Could this thing be really flying?" then say so. If the question is "Could this thing be an alien mothership?" then say so. I don't believe the question you really want to ask is "Is this unidentified object that appears to be flying in the sky a real unidentified flying object?"

Comment: @the_drow:  The "F" in UFO (as @Oddthinking already pointed out) is for "Flying," so you implied it in the title of your question.

Comment: @Oddthinking: @RandolfRichardson: The question being asked is if this is a fake computer generated/a reflection of something or a known physical phenomena or it's a genuine real UFO. If you'd answer it might be a real UFO I'd be intrigued to question further. I'm not sure how you want me to clarify my question furthermore than it is already.

Comment: @the_drow, my problem here is purely one of definition. If you see something weird in the sky, it is called a UFO. Many UFOs turn out to be birds, balloons, satellites, car lights or other natural phenomena. Some UFOs remain unexplained. Some people think the unexplained UFOs are actually alien spaceships. But whether they are ball lightning or Martians, the sighting is still of a UFO. Are hoaxes also considered UFOs? I would say yes (but others may disagree). So when you ask is it a *genuine* *real* UFO, that's not meaningful. I think you mean "Is it an E.T.?"

Comment: @Oddthinking: I won't even start considering the possibility of an alien mothership of some sort if this is a hoax.

Comment: Oh, I think I might understand now. Your question is "Is this a known hoax, or are these really unexplained lights in the sky?" Is that right? So, and answer that "These are geese, and I can prove it" would be almost off-topic :-)

Comment: @Oddthinking: Exactly. Would you care what that object is if it's a hoax?

Comment: How come the camera work on these things is always so shoddy? I would be more impressed if they filmed it right. Especially if the guys are from Beam.TV or whatever. Bunch of wankers...

Comment: Looks like a plastic carrier bag (or similar sized _'flying'_ refuse) that the wind is playing with and is reflecting low angle but bright sunlight when clear from the cloud, and _'disappearing'_ when there's not much light to reflect when in/under/over the cloud. And the rest are just birds, and there's absolutely no reason to suspect otherwise. I don't think it's faked, though. It's most likely an authentic footage of unidentified flying garbage (UFG).

Comment: The video with the tower bridge in it is pretty revealing: the camera is handheld, thus slightly wobbly, changing the camera angle, while parts of the path of the dots is perfectly straight, even during camera wobble, - indicating that either the dots were added to the footage without proper tracking, or the phenomenon that caused the dots caused the camera to wobble :) (no answer, as this would count as own research)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commenter, [SubZero1703](https://www.youtube.com/user/SubZero1703) pointed out on this [YouTube video of (apparently) the same phenomena](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiylJCma9c),  at the [20 second mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtiylJCma9c&t=0m20s) there is point where the camera moves, and the UFOs move with it.

It is unlikely that real world objects would happen to speed-up/slow-down exactly in time with the camera movement.

This is highly suggestive that the UFOs are fakes, added in post-production, with a small glitch in their camera-tracking.

There have been some claims that the work was done by [Beam.TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM.TV), who have an office nearby the video you cited, but I haven't found any substantive evidence of that.